# Get clicked element in typescript

Tags: typescript, event-handling, dom-events

I am converting my show/hide javascript function to typescript. I decided to ask after spending half a day searching how to get the source `HTMLElement` that create the click event in typescript. I find a way but I think there should be better way to do it. Please help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>show/hide</title>
    <script src="../build/getClickedElement.js"></script>
    <style>
        .hidden{
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <button onclick="getClickedElement();">show/hide</button>
    <div class="hidden">
        <p>aaa</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <button onclick="getClickedElement();">show/hide</button>
    <div class="hidden">
        <p>bbb</p>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

````js
const getClickedElement = function () {
    let event = window.event;
    let eventTarget = event.target;
    let elClicked = eventTarget;
    showHideTS(elClicked);
};
const showHideTS = function (elClicked) {
    let elParent = elClicked.parentElement;
    let elDiv = elParent.querySelector('div');
    elDiv.classList.toggle("hidden");
};
// const showHideJS = function () {
//     let elTarget = event.target;
//     let elParent = elTarget.parentElement;
//     let elDiv = elParent.querySelector('div');
//     elDiv.classList.toggle("hidden");
// }```
````